# Is SQL Having clause syntactic sugar?

Tags: sql, database, dml

Just curious if the HAVING clause in SQL is just [a syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for WHERE-clause over subquery?

For example:

```
SELECT DepartmentName, COUNT(*) 
 FROM Employee, Department 
 WHERE Employee.DepartmentID = Department.DepartmentID 
 GROUP BY DepartmentName
 HAVING COUNT(*)>1;
```

is equivalent in result to

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT DepartmentName AS deptNam, COUNT(*) AS empCnt
   FROM Employee AS emp, Department AS dept
   WHERE emp.DepartmentID = dept.DepartmentID
   GROUP BY deptNam
) AS grp
WHERE grp.empCnt > 1;
```

In this way one could rewrite HAVING with subquery+WHERE.

So the only difference is number of printed characters + DB vendor specifics?

(examples from Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Having_(SQL))

Comment: HAVING is core ANSI SQL, derived tables is an ANSI SQL extension (Feature F591.) Besides, HAVING has been there for ages, derived tables are slightly newer.

Comment: Some cheap databases' optimizer will be able to handle the first one gracefully, but could have trouble with the second one. They won't be able to rephrase the query.

Comment: By that logic, either  JOIN or WHERE clause is also syntactic sugar?

Comment: @CaiusJard: I doubt you could filter without WHERE clause, thus without HAVING I think I could filter aggregates with sub-queries.

Comment: `SELECT p.* FROM person p INNER JOIN (SELECT 'Smith' as LastName FROM DUAL) x ON x.LastName = p.LastName` is a no-where equivalent of `SELECT * FROM person WHERE p.LastName = 'Smith'`; my point is largely that just because there are a couple of ways of doing something doesn't necessarily mean that one is syntactic sugar for the other. HAVING is a where clause that is done after a group. WHERE is done before group, but `WHERE GROUP HAVING` certainly be rewritten as `(WHERE GROUP) WHERE` - whether or not it's sugar in the purest sense depends on the particular DB implementing it

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `HAVING` is "syntactic sugar" in the sense that it can always be replaced by a subquery or CTE.  I will note that some databases have a tendency to materialize subqueries, so that can add a small amount of additional overhead.  And MySQL extends the use of `HAVING` in non-aggregation contexts.

That said, commas in the `FROM` clause are *worse* than syntactic sugar.  They are essentially obsolete, having been replaced by proper `JOIN` syntax in the 1990s -- that's the last millennium.  They are less powerful, because they don't support outer joins.

So, you should put your efforts to learning proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax rather than worrying about `HAVING`.

```
FROM Employee e JOIN
     Department d
     ON e.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID
```

You should also learn to qualify *all* column references in your queries.

Comment: Wasn't there something with + you added to the where expression if you waned a left or right join?

Comment: @Magnus The `(+)` was an Oracle extension prior to SQL-92. It was a breakthrough at the time, but much less powerful than the SQL-92 joins.

Comment: @TheImpaler: and even Oracle discourages the use of `(+)` for outer joins

Comment: [But Db2 has introduced it recently! :)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/doc/r0052878.html)

Comment: Db2 also discounted this "wheel" thingy as something that would never catch on, and has planned next year to look into this new-fangled thing called "fire", thinking it might be hot.

Comment: @LukasEder . . . And to think that they could have implemented something useful with the effort to put that it.  I guess that is how IBM works.  Perhaps that functionality was been in the development queue for 15 years.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Useful for whom? For the poor souls who have to migrate 100000s of lines of 30 year old SQL from Oracle to Db2 because of some C-Level decision?